# What part of the skeleton produces the most blood cells?

Tags: blood, bones, bone-marrow

If I understood correctly, blood cells (haematids, leukocytes, platelets, etc.) are made in red bone marrow, which is in many bones of the body, but specially in some bones and fewer with development.

But what part of the skeleton produces the most amount of blood cells? I have heard it is the vertebral column, but I did not find a source.

Comment: No worries. It's allowed, and although it's very thin on prior research, you did at least make it clear that you've done some homework on the subject and that you tried and failed to find confirmation of your findings. That's really all our prior research policy requires.

Comment: On all sites on SE, you can just click [help] (that's the ? link at the top) and then click [What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).